# Ubuntu 16.10 extend partition from unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

i did not realise that I needed more space back then.
I have almost no space left, I resized the windows HDD from windows.
Now I have 15 gb unallocated space, I want to extend to my ubuntu partition.

[image: gparted picture of space]

How do I do it properly?

EDIT: I created a bootable iso with rufus (16.04 iso) and ran it and then clicked "Try ubuntu" but i still cant increase the sda3 [gparted picture from usb try ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abgzi.png)

EDIT EDIT: Swapoff did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from Live CD.
Start **gparted**, increase the extended partition /dev/sda3 first, then increase /dev/sda5.

Comment: Should i backup things or is this safe?

Comment: Always have a backup when messing with the system ;-)

Comment: How much should i increase each? Does it matter or? What is what btw?

Comment: Its good practice to make a backup. The increase will probably end successfully but you will be very unhappy if it doesn't and you lost data. I would add the entire unallocated space if I were you.
 "What is what BTW" ?  I assume you mean the extended partition? Look at it as a disk within a disk. First you must increase the other disk before the inner disk can be increased. For a full technical description Google it.

Comment: I cant increase sda3? See this pic [link](http://imgur.com/a/woxEU) imgur!

Comment: Did you boot from Live CD ?   You can't increase the partition if you booted from it.

Comment: Live CD? I downloaded ubuntu iso and used rufus to create usb, than ran USB and i clicked "try ubuntu" is this the same?

Comment: Yes, it is. The key-symbol means the partition is locked, usually when you boot from it. On second look (and with my glasses on) you see another key-symbol next to the swap. Right click swap and select 'swap off'. I expect both key-symbols to disappear. If so, you should be able to proceed. Afterwards turn swap on again.

Comment: Oh nice, that did the trick! Should i increase the sda3 with all the unallocted space(15gb) or 7.5gb to sda3 and sda5?

Comment: You MUST increase sda3 first before you can increase sda5. If you try sda5 first you get an error saying No space available.

Comment: Yes done i increased sda3 with all gb, but when i want to increase sda5 it says this error: Imgur: [link](http://imgur.com/a/IW5Eh)

Comment: Ow.. bummer. Yes, I had the same error some time ago. Updating e2fsck is indeed the solution. Let me find the link to how to update e2fsck and I'll be back !

Comment: Okay, im waiting for that link :)

Comment: Support for checksums is  in e2fsprogs 1.43.

Since Ubuntu Yakktey has e2fsprogs v1.43.3 you don't have to build it from source any longer. Instead, if you have Ubuntu Trusty or newer, you can download the Deb packages for e2fsprogs and e2fslibs for your architecture and install it with:

sudo dpkg -i e2fs{libs,progs}_*_$(dpkg --print-architecture).deb

Please know this will not change the Live USB. You will have to do this every time you boot from Live USB.
Another solution might be to download 16.10 ISO and put it to USB.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for the help. Downloaded 17. Checked  the sda5 and ran fix then it helps now done!  :)

Comment: Great, glad to help !